# iOS: isMultipleTouchEnabled does not work on table

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a controller that has a UITableView property:

```
class OrdersViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var ordersTable: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.ordersTable.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false;
  }
```

However, it's not working. When I try swiping two cells at the same time (using this library https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell) it still swipes both of them:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To be able to swipe both of them at the same time or not?

Comment: I don't want them to be swipeable at the same time. Just one at a time

Comment: When you are getting your cells, set `cell.isExclusiveTouch = true` for each cell and give it another try.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622519-ismultipletouchenabled) about `isMultipleTouchEnabled`:

> When set to true, the receiver receives all touches associated with a multi-touch sequence. When set to false, the receiver receives only the first touch event in a multi-touch sequence. The default value of this property is false.
>   Other views in the same window can still receive touch events when this property is false. If you want this view to handle multi-touch events exclusively, set the values of both this property and the is​Exclusive​Touch property to true.

So, even though the table itself won't handle multi-touch, it's child views handle single touches independently. 
To achieve what you want you probably have to set `isExclusiveTouch` on all cells.